# C preprocessor float operations

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, ansi-c

Assume working on a platform that does not consist of a hardware FPU (code is developed in C with GCC originated compiler). In the code there is an equation that is resolved on a preprocessor level:

```
uint16_t result1 = (100 * 5) / 4; 
uint16_t result2 = 100 * 1.25;
```

Are there any practical differences for the assembly generated for both cases `result1` and `result2`? Does the fact that the target MCU has no hardware FPU changes anything for the preprocessor calculations?

Clarification:

Will the above code at run time be equal to:

```
uint16_t result1 = 125; 
uint16_t result2 = 125;
```

?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Evaluation of these expressions is done in phase 7 (semantic analysis and translation, the main compilation phase) of translation, not phase 4 (preprocessing). (It could also be deferred to program execution.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil the second case is very unlikely (or rather impossible) if we consider `gcc`.The question is about gcc not hypothetical DM

Comment: If you are asking about the equivalence of similar pairs expressions, then this pair may be insufficient to express the general problem. For example, `uint16_t r1 = 120 * 2 / 3)` might produce a different result than `uint16_t r2 = 120 * (2. / 3)`. You will need to describe the problem more fully.

Comment: Please notice that I have used brackets, so there is no other way for the given expression `(VAL * 5) / 4` to yield other result than 125. I am asking only about this specific case. There is no bigger question behind this.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any practical differences for the assembly generated for both cases

No. Both cases can be calculated at compile time.

However, there can be reasons to prefer the first. Integer operations are 100% predictable, which float operations are not. In this case, it would not make a difference, but in others it would.

> Will the above code at compile time be converted to:

Very likely. However, nothing mandates this. If you're using `gcc` without optimizations, it's likely that this will not happen, because that compiler has no optimizations enabled by default.

Comment: Integer operations are not exact; `7/3` produces a truncated result worse than the floating-point result, and we do not know the full class of expressions the OP really intends to ask about.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True. "Predictable" was the word I was looking for.

Comment: There is no full expression here. Its just this exact equation I am asking about. Since I have used brackets with `uint16_t result1 = (VAL * 5) / 4; `, there should be no fractional division. I have removed the `#define` statement to decrease obfuscation of the question.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Yes, we're not talking about precedence and such. I'm saying that it could be problem if you instead had an equation where the value is very sensitive to small changes of the variables.